# Using CSS or JS to hide text inside the a href tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list in this format:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="link">Part 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am using css `:before` to display something instead of the text inside the `a href` tag and I want to hide the text. I just want to hide Part 1, Part 2, Part 3 text and leave a href tag there.

If I use `display:none;` then everything is hidden, how can I just hide the text inside the href tag?

Comment: visibility:hidden;

Comment: As the content of the pseudo-element isn't in the DOM it can't be selected by the users (this may be by-design), but it may also be inaccessible to screen-readers. I have no better solution to offer, but please consider your users, and their potential difficulties with your content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually done by negative indentation, which is SEO friendly; opposed to `visibility: hidden;` or `display:none;`

```
display: inline-block;
text-indent: -999px;
```

But since you need the `:before` pseudo on the **same element** the above will not work well,
therefore **font-size** might be a better solution for your case:

```css
li a{
  font-size: 0;            /* make really small */
}

li a:before{
  content: "CLICK";
  font-size: 1rem;         /* reset to 1 root-em for the pseudo */
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="link">Part 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Beside `font-size` you could try `opacity` (0), `color` (transparent) etc...

Comment: that's not clickable (?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the visibility attribute, it will collapse (hide) the contents of your href tag but keep the tag inline.

css

```
ul li a {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="link">Part 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

To show the contents at a later stage use

```
ul li a {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I just hide the text inside the href tag?

simply set the `font-size` to `0`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
    a{
      font-size: 0; 
    }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="link">Part 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 3</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's not clickable (?)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue with only the Part 1, Part 2 etc hidden.

```
ul li a {
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li a:before {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

The other declaration is necessary, or your :before text is hidden as well. This will keep your anchor intact, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your text color the same as the background-color (white in this example). The advantage is, that the link space is still there, when you move the mouse over it, keeping it clickable.

```css
li a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="link">Part 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Part 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `color: transparent` if this approach is used (if only to save the time of having to manually assign the correct background color); but Google - and presumably other search engines - won't appreciate this (though the down-vote isn't mine).

Comment: @DavidThomas why? the HTML is not changed - I can't imagine text colors being relevant for Google...

Comment: From memory - and this is largely why I haven't down-voted - Google considers 'hidden text' (such as text that's indistinguishable from the background color over which it lays) to be something along the lines of 'keyword stuffing,' a practice by which potential keywords are added to the page, in order to perform 'better,' or be rated more highly, by search engines.

Comment: @DavidThomas well, but the question is all about hiding text. And if Google is smart enough (which it most likely is), it will recognize every method to hide text.

Comment: Perhaps, or perhaps eventually; but as noted: the down-vote is entirely coincidental to my comments; my comments are my opinions and I fully accept that they may be right, wrong or in some nebulous undefined state.